# How to communicate between c# and python applications efficiently

Tags: python, c#

I have a C# application that receives information from a Python CLI application by running commands.

I do not have access to modify the Python application.

For each command I created a Process.

In an attempt to streamline the process, I created a Python script that is used as a Wrapper, I create one Process in the C# application and work with it, but as mentioned, each Wrapper command creates a process in Python and returns me the answer.
I think this is more effective but not enough.

I want to try to optimize the application by working with one process running in the background, third party tools, libraries, or think of another way to optimize the application.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MainApp
{
    public class CommandManager
    {
        public string GetHelpCommand()
        {
            return "/usr/phyPROGRAM.py -help";
        }
    }

    public class PythonExecutor : IDisposable
    {
        private Process pythonProcess;
        private StringBuilder outputBuilder;
        private TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs;

        public PythonExecutor()
        {
            InitializePythonProcess();
        }

        private void InitializePythonProcess()
        {
            pythonProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = {
                    FileName = "python3",
                    Arguments = "/usr/wrapper.py",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };

            outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            pythonProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Data == "##END##")
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(outputBuilder.ToString());
                    outputBuilder.Clear();
                }
                else if (e.Data != null)
                {
                    outputBuilder.AppendLine(e.Data);
                }
            };

            pythonProcess.Start();
            pythonProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }

        public Task<string> ExecuteCommand(string command)
        {
            tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
            pythonProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            pythonProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
            pythonProcess.WaitForExit();
            pythonProcess.Dispose();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            CommandManager cmdManager = new CommandManager();

            using PythonExecutor executor = new PythonExecutor();
            string command1 = cmdManager.GetHelpCommand();
            string result1 = await executor.ExecuteCommand(command1);
            Console.WriteLine(result1);
           
            executor.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Python Wrapper script:

```
import sys
import subprocess

def execute_main_script(command):
    try:
        # Here, we use the subprocess module to execute the given command and return output
        result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        return result.decode('utf-8')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        return e.output.decode('utf-8')

while True:
    command = sys.stdin.readline().strip()  # Read command from stdin
    if command == "exit":
        break
    else:
        output = execute_main_script(command)
        print(output, end='',flush=True)  # Send output to stdout
        print("##END##",flush=True)
```

Comment: What exactly does the Python wrapper script achieve that you couldn't do directly from a C# `Process`?

Comment: lighter process from what i understand

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify the Python code to actually run a server process, then executing a one off command process is the best you can do

But if you can, then gRPC or web frameworks are commonly used, if not otherwise writing your own protocol on a raw server `socket` connection

Worth pointing out that your code is subject to command injection attacks since you're directly passing user input into a subprocess to execute, so you should validate input first, as well as make sure to run the code with limited permissions user account